# How to parse timestamp to Unix-Time?

Tags: parsing, time, timestamp, influxdb

Im sorry if mistakes will appear. I was not speaking english for 6 years.

I was looking on google/github for some software that can parse my performance monitoring data to the understandable format of InfluxDB. There are some Programms that deal with very specific data, or is written in languages i dont now (javascript, go).

My language is Java.

I have time stamps like "10/07/2016 10:57:13.982"
How can I get the Unix-Time out of this stamp?

Comment: InfluxDB's time formats are fixed and documented; there are no options beyond what is specified. To use a different format in your app, you'll need to use whatever date/time parser your language provides, or roll your own. What language or environment are you using? Python? Go? Java? R? Excel? ...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was searching for this in bash, as I am implementing incremental backups for the influx database. Use the following:

```
date --utc +%FT%TZ
```